# Adding Business page link to website

Tags: facebook

I am trying to put a link on my website to my business page but it keeps sending my customers to my personal page. How do I change this to go to just my business page?

Answer (score 0):

Get a facebook icon and just copy the URL from your facebook business page.

```
<a target="_blank" href="URL" title="Facebook Page">
<img src="images/facebook.png" height="30px" width="30px"/>
</a>
```